# Quack mode is unable to find local manuals

Tags: osx, scheme, manual

I've been interested in trying out [Quack mode](http://www.neilvandyke.org/quack/) in my Scheme environment recently, but have been running into some problems with its keyword documentation. According to [`quack.el`](http://www.neilvandyke.org/quack/quack.el), invoking `quack-view-keyword-docs` should allow me to view the manual documentation for a given keyword, although it currently only works for PLT manuals. Nonetheless, when I do invoke said function with a given keyword, say `xml`, I get the following series of errors:

```
Quack Warning: Manual plt-mzscheme has no HTML.
Quack Warning: Manual plt-mzlib has no HTML.
Quack Warning: Manual plt-mred has no HTML.
Quack Warning: Manual plt-framework has no HTML.
Quack Warning: Manual plt-drscheme has no HTML.
Quack Warning: Manual plt-insidemz has no HTML.
Quack Warning: Manual plt-tools has no HTML.
Quack Warning: Manual plt-mzc has no HTML.
Quack Warning: Manual plt-r5rs has no HTML.
Sorry, no documentation found for keyword "xml".
```

This isn't making sense to me since I have supplied the `quack-pltcollect-dirs` variable with my `collects` directory like so:

```
(quote ("/Applications/Racket v6.5/collects"))
```

I did this as per the instructions in [`quack.el`](http://www.neilvandyke.org/quack/quack.el):

> Note to PLT Scheme users: If you do not already have the PLT manuals installed, they can be downloaded from  `http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/` and installed in your PLT `doc` collection.  If Quack is not finding installed PLT manuals, then be sure that the `quack-pltcollect-dirs` variable contains the appropriate collection directory (if it does not, then either set the `PLTHOME` and/or `PLTCOLLECTS` environment variables appropriately, or set `quack-pltcollect-dirs`).

I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing here that is causing Quack mode to fail every time I try to look up the docs for a keyword. Btw, I am using Emacs 25.1 on OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: I suspect the fact that this mode has been written for Emacs 23 (and been tested with manuals of the same age) has to do with it...

Comment: @wasamasa Hmm, I didn't even realize that; that may indeed be a problem. Tbh, I've quite given up on making this particular package work and have had more success with the (seemingly) similar [`geiser`](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) package, but I'll leave this question open in case anyone finds a solution.

Comment: I think the organization of the documentation has changed a lot since PLT Scheme was reborn as Racket (which was in 2010-ish).

Comment: @molbdnilo Quite possible; I have no reference for comparison, though, since I've only seen the Racket docs.